# Will pthread_join halt the parent program if the child thread is still working?.. Will pthread_detach make it faster?? instead of using join?

Tags: sockets, pthreads, posix

My program is something like this.. I wanted to know will I make my program slow, if I call pthread join???

```
void* a(void *a)
{
 do---something();//which is a very long procedure, I mean takes a lot of time...
 pthread_exit();
}

main()
{
 while(1)
 {
  pthread_create(a);
  pthread_join(a);
 }
}
```

So, if I call pthread_join, will I halt at that point until the child thread finishes it execution, or do I go on and create one more thread ?????

Comment: The problem is that, I am writing a socket programm where I receive a packet and create a thread, and this child goes on to write in a file which takes a bit of time. Further, I have around 800000 packets coming, and I can't create so many threads, as max is 256 threads, even I reduce the stack, I can't create so many... and if I don't call pthread_join then the child thread never clears its stack... As, I read somewhere unless and until a pthread_join is called the child never gives up its stack... is it true??...What is the best solution you give me for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pthread_join() blocks until the child thread has exited, but you still want/need to call it in order for the child thread to be cleaned up properly once it has gone away.  But as you say you don't want to have your main thread blocked, so how to deal with this?  The way I would do it is to have the child thread send a message (via socket-pair or some other mechanism) back to its parent thread just before it exits.... when the parent thread receives this message, then it knows that now is a good time to call pthread_join(), since the child thread is already gone (or almost gone) and therefore pthread_join will never block (or at least not for more than a few milliseconds).

Answer (score 2):

From [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html):

> The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling
>   thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread
>   has already terminated.

If this is not what you want, either defer the call to pthread_join (putting all of the pthread_t's in a container so you can join them later) or use [pthread_detach](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) so you do not need to join them at all.

Comment: The problem is that, I am writing a socket programm where I receive a packet and create a thread, and this child goes on to write in a file which takes a bit of time. Further, I have around 800000 packets coming, and I can't create so many threads, as max is 256 threads, even I reduce the stack, I can't create so many... and if I don't call pthread_join then the child thread never clears its stack... As, I read somewhere unless and until a pthread_join is called the child never gives up its stack... is it true??...What is the best solution you give me for this??

Comment: Please follow the link I included for `pthread_detach`.  If you use `pthread_detach` you do not need to invoke `pthread_join`.  (ALthough if you really are creating 800,000 threads, you may want to re-think your design.  Read about "thread pools"...)

Comment: In reality I don't want create them, but, they are living for few micro sec's I mean just write into file and die... So, I wanted to use them?? .. Can you give me a idea or a link where I can learn about thread pool??

Answer (score 1):

the join call blocks until the thread exits

Comment: The problem is that, I am writing a socket programm where I receive a packet and create a thread, and this child goes on to write in a file which takes a bit of time. Further, I have around 800000 packets coming, and I can't create so many threads, as max is 256 threads, even I reduce the stack, I can't create so many... and if I don't call pthread_join then the child thread never clears its stack... As, I read somewhere unless and until a pthread_join is called the child never gives up its stack... is it true??...What is the best solution you give me for this??

Comment: As mentioned by other respondants you can call pthread_detach so you don't have to join. However this isn't really going to work that well as the thread overhead and synchronisation in the disk io is going to distroy your throughput. A _much_ better solution is to use a thread pool. Put your incomming packets on a queue and have each worker in the pool repeatedly take the next item and write it.  Also if it's all being written to the same file then you might be better with a single thread for that file. - use the queue so that your rcvthread does the minimum between packets

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use non-blocking sockets to handle many clients without having to create a thread for each. See often quoted [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) for more details.

Comment: I have used a non-blocking socket... but, I am transferring 1GB file on UDP.. and the kernel is also getting filled at slow rate then the sender.. So, I am creating a thread, so that the writing overhead goes away from the receiving thread.. hope, you got my point...

Comment: If you are transferring the file over UDP you need to throttle yourself to avoid congesting the network or swamping the receiver. Hence, you only need to read the file in small chunks and pace the sending.

Comment: So, will detach do some good at the receiving side, I mean it will halt the parent right.. as join will do?